# Complex-valued ODE from PDE in python

Tags: python, ode

I have a complexed valued system from a PDE problem, the odeint() in Python cannot deal with it. I wrote a RK4 module to solve my system. It seems to work, however, the computed values are obvious incorrect. At the second time step, whole computed values are zero. Here are my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import drawnow
import time
import math

### Parameters ###
L       = 20
n       = 64
delta_t = 1.
tmax    = 10
miu     = 1e-6
x2      = np.linspace(-L/2,L/2, n+1)
x       = x2[:n]                         # periodic B.C. #0 = #n

kx1     = np.linspace(0,n/2-1,n/2)
kx2     = np.linspace(1,n/2,  n/2)
kx2     = -1*kx2[::-1]
kx      = (2.*math.pi/L)*np.concatenate((kx1,kx2)); kx[0] = 1e-6
ky      = kx;                                       y     = x

X, Y    = np.meshgrid(x, y)
KX,KY   = np.meshgrid(kx,ky)
K       = KX**2 + KY**2
K2      = np.reshape(K, n**2,1)

### Initial Condition ###
vorticity = np.exp(-0.25*X**2 - 2.*Y**2)
wt        = np.fft.fft2(vorticity)
wt2       = np.reshape(wt, n**2, 1)     # wt2 is initial condition
### Define ODE ###  
def yprime(t,rhs):  
    global miu, K, K2,n,KX, KY, wt2, wt 
    psit = -wt/ K   
    psix = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KX*psit))
    psiy = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KY*psit))
    wx   = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KX*wt))
    wy   = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KY*wt))
    rhs  = -miu * K2 * wt2 + np.reshape(np.fft.fft2(wx*psiy - wy*psix), n**2,1)
    return rhs

def RK4(domain,wt2,tmax):
    w = np.empty((tmax+1,n**2))
    w = w + 0j
    t = np.empty(tmax+1)        # length
    w[0,:] = wt2                # enter initial conditions in y
    t[0]   = domain[0]
    for i in range(1,tmax):
        t[i+1] = t[i]+delta_t
        w[i+1,:] = RK4Step(t[i], w[i,:],delta_t)
    return w

def RK4Step(t,w,delta_t):
    k1 = yprime(t,w)
    k2 = yprime(t+0.5*delta_t, w+0.5*k1*delta_t)
    k3 = yprime(t+0.5*delta_t, w+0.5*k2*delta_t)
    k4 = yprime(t+delta_t,     w+k3*delta_t)
    return w + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*delta_t/6. 

### Prediction ###
TimeStart = 0.
TimeEnd   = tmax+1
TimeSpan  = np.arange(TimeStart, TimeEnd, delta_t)
wt2_sol   = RK4(TimeSpan, wt2, tmax)

for i in TimeSpan:
    w = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(np.reshape(wt2_sol[i,:], (n, n))))
    plt.pcolor(X,Y,w,shading = 'interp',cmap='jet')
    drawnow
    time.sleep(0.2)
    plt.show()
```

Any idea why it doesn't work? In addition, I like to make a short video based on the solution. the function 'drawnow' and 'time.sleep() do not seem to work here.

Thank you!

Comment: Your differential equation appears to be a simple time integration. In `yprime(t,rhs)` there is no dependence on rhs on the right hand side. Could you also please document the "raw" form of the PDE you are trying to solve?

Comment: The 'raw' form of the PDE is: dw/dt = miu* laplacian(w)-d(psi)/dx * dw/dy + d(psi)/dy * dw/dx. I used spectral method  to transform this PDE to ODE. The 'rhs' in the function 'yprime' is the 'Fourier Transform' of this PDE. So, if the RK4 works, 'wt2_sol   = RK4(TimeSpan, wt2, tmax)' should give me the solutions in Fourier space. @Lutzl

Comment: Then replace first `def yprime(t,rhs):` with `def yprime(t,wt):`, since `w` resp. `wt` is your state variable, and `rhs` which should be `lhs` is the result. So `wt, wt2` are local variables. You should care that the input and output of `yprime` have the same format, if one is a vector, then the other should be a vector, with the inverse pair of `reshape` commands in between. But probably you can leave it as a 2D array of grid values, so that no reshape anywhere is necessary.

Comment: And if you do not know how to use `drawnow`, why not use `matplotlib.animate` which seems to be better integrated.

Comment: Thank you, LutzlL. @LutzL. I finally made this code work (I posted as below), and used the **matplotlib.animate** to create an animation. However, the results seems to be weird compared to the results I got from **ode45** in **Matlab**. Do you have any idea why? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My cleaned up version. Changing the number of inner steps does not change the quality of the result.

- Make the Runge-Kutta solver (more) universal, input time array with `(times[0],y0)` being the initial point of the IVP
- replace `def yprime(t,rhs):` with `def yprime(t,wt):`, since `wt` is your state variable, and `rhs` is the result. So `wt` is a local variable in `yprime`. Eliminate `rhs` by direct assembly in the return statement.
- remove all `reshape` operation, act on the vector space of 2D arrays, numpy is good in treating matrices as some other kind of vector
- add `matplotlib.animate` for the pre-generated image sequence. The tutorial for that seemed easier than the function-based animation
- Played with `arange` to replace `linspace` in generation of `kx`. Better option is probably to use `fftshift` to swap the halves of the frequency array

.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

#----- Numerical integration of ODE via fixed-step classical Runge-Kutta -----

def RK4Step(yprime,t,y,dt):
    k1 = yprime(t       , y          )
    k2 = yprime(t+0.5*dt, y+0.5*k1*dt)
    k3 = yprime(t+0.5*dt, y+0.5*k2*dt)
    k4 = yprime(t+    dt, y+    k3*dt)
    return y + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*dt/6. 

def RK4(yprime,times,y0):
    y = np.empty(times.shape+y0.shape,dtype=y0.dtype)
    y[0,:] = y0                 # enter initial conditions in y
    steps = 4
    for i in range(times.size-1):
        dt = (times[i+1]-times[i])/steps
        y[i+1,:] = y[i,:]
        for k in range(steps):
            y[i+1,:] = RK4Step(yprime, times[i]+k*dt, y[i+1,:], dt)
    return y

#====================================================================
#----- Parameters for PDE -----
L       = 20
n       = 64
delta_t = 1.
tmax    = 10
miu     = 1e-6

#----- Constructing the grid and kernel functions
x2      = np.linspace(-L/2,L/2, n+1)
x       = x2[:n]                         # periodic B.C. #0 = #n
y       = x

kx     = np.linspace( -n/2  , n/2-1, n)
kx      = (2.*math.pi/L)*np.concatenate((np.arange(0,n/2),np.arange(-n/2,0))); 
kx[0] = 1e-6
ky      = kx;                                       

X, Y    = np.meshgrid(x, y)
KX,KY   = np.meshgrid(kx,ky)
K       = KX**2 + KY**2

#----- Initial Condition -----
vorticity = np.exp(-0.25*X**2 - 2.*Y**2)
wt0       = np.fft.fft2(vorticity)

#----- Define ODE -----
def wprime(t,wt):  
    global miu, K, K2,n,KX, KY 
    psit = -wt / K   
    psix = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KX*psit))
    psiy = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KY*psit))
    wx   = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KX*wt))
    wy   = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(1j*KY*wt))
    return  -miu * K * wt + np.fft.fft2(wx*psiy - wy*psix)

#====================================================================
#----- Compute the numerical solution -----
TimeStart = 0.
TimeEnd   = tmax+delta_t
TimeSpan  = np.arange(TimeStart, TimeEnd, delta_t)
wt_sol    = RK4(wprime,TimeSpan, wt0)

#----- Animate the numerical solution -----
fig = plt.figure()
ims = []
for i in TimeSpan:
    w = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(wt_sol[i,:]))
    im = plt.pcolor(X,Y,w,edgecolors='none',cmap='jet')
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
    repeat_delay=1000)

#ani.save('PDE-animation.mp4')

plt.show()
```